# Cannot install python libraries on Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

[image]

I installed PyCharm and and Python 3 using the zip file. Now I want to install various libraries but it would not allow me to do so. How should I install the libraries on PyCharm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools` should get the work done.

Link : https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Since OP is using windows, `python -m pip install -U pip setuptools` should get the work done.

Comment: I use Windows. Where do I type the sudo thing?

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to install `setuptools`

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

***Important Step:***

Open Command Prompt in Windows
And Type `pip install python3-setuptools`

**If First Step is throwing some Error**

To solve this,you need to let python know where the pip packages are to do this follow the instructions below

First  Go to Settings and select Project interpreter, now Click on Add button and switch to  manage repositories option and now again press add button and type
`https://pypi.python.org/pypi` in the box and save.

Now Restart your pycharm and it will work.

Comment: It will be,can you try the first step and restart pycharm and try.?

Comment: I tried the first step and it says 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I think this is probably because I could not "install" python on my computer using the exe file.. for administrator issue. I was able to download the python zip file.

Comment: Try this `python -m pip install -U pip setuptools`

Comment: it says python is not recognized as an internal or external command.... lol

Comment: Great Either u didnt install the python or u didnt setup the Environment Path.Go the C:/ and you will find Python installed or otherwise install a fresh Python setup.Good Luck

Comment: I changed the python directory folder and typed python -m pip install -U pip setuptools and it says "No module named pip". The problem is that I cannot install a fresh Python setup using the exe file. I have to rely on the embed zip file.